# exchanging items within a gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

In the following method, I am trying to exchange two items within the grid view by clicking on one. I have numbers `0-9` and by clicking on one item, other than `0`, the item will place itself in position on `0` and the `0` will be set in the place of clicked item. I think I am missing the line of inserting the `0` into its place. Please see the following code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Item clickedItem = mList.get(position);
        int g = clickedItem.getValue();
        String c = clickedItem.getStr();
        Item spare = mList.get(8);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "val is "+g+",", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (clickedItem.getValue() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unable to find pic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (clickedItem.getValue() != 0) {
            Item temp = getItem(position);
            // need clicked position to get spare;
            spare = temp;
        }
    }

    public Item getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Item clickedItem = mList.get(position);
            int g = clickedItem.getValue();
            String c = clickedItem.getStr();
            Item spare = mList.get(8);


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "val is "+g+",", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (clickedItem.getValue()== 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unable to find pic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return
            }

            if (clickedItem.getValue()!= 0) {
                Item temp = getItem(position);
                Item temp0 = getItem(0);
                tempPosition = position;
                mList.remove(tempPosition );
                mList.remove(0);
                mList.add(0,temp );
                if(tempPosition > mList.size() - 1){
                    mList.add(temp0);
                }else{
                    mList.add(tempPosition ,temp0);
                }

                mAdapter.notifDataSetChanged();
                // need clicked position to get spare;
                spare=temp;
            }

        }

        public Item getItem(int position) {
            return mList.get(position);
        }


    });
```

Comment: I Couldn't edit your answer, please add the first lines as a code.